# Access hard-coded data in MVC controller using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I have some knowledge about Angularjs but I'm new to ASP.NET MVC.
So I was following this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api tutorial. But I came up with a problem as it uses Jquery. I want to access the hard coded data in below controller using Angular.

```
using ProductsApp.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace ProductsApp.Controllers
{
    public class ProductsController : ApiController
    {
        Product[] products = new Product[] 
        { 
            new Product { Id = 1, Name = "Tomato Soup", Category = "Groceries", Price = 1 }, 
            new Product { Id = 2, Name = "Yo-yo", Category = "Toys", Price = 3.75M }, 
            new Product { Id = 3, Name = "Hammer", Category = "Hardware", Price = 16.99M } 
        };

        public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
        {
            return products;
        }

        public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(int id)
        {
            var product = products.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);
            if (product == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(product);
        }
    }
}
```

I just want the method to access the data.

Can anyone help me with this. Thanks

Comment: It will be similar - see [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Answer (score 0):

Use `$http` in your service or controller of AngularJS to access data from your Web API. For example:

```
$http.get("http://localhost:8080/api/products/getallproducts")
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.data);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If writing WebApi application then you need to change the IHttpActionResult Name to Get. and try this URL:

```
localhost:8080/api/products/{id}
```

*{id} is optional.

if you want to use the route you should change `WebApiConfig.cs` in App_Start folder.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at angularjs [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service which is used to establish communication with the http server in situation as yours.

To call `GetAllProducts()`, using the `$http`, use the route `"api/products"` like this

```
$http.get("api/products")
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
});
```

And to call `GetProduct()` use the route `"api/products/1"` if your product is 1 like this

```
$http.get("api/products/1")
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
});
```